# Good connection to Internet but poor connection to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a small Linux box. If I ping google.com from this box, I get no packet loss and very fast rtt (min 14/ avg 17/ max 27, no packet loss).

If I ping any other box *on the same network* or have any other box ping it, I get terrible results (88/1115/3144 with 71% packet loss).

It's similar but not *as* bad if I repeat the experiment with other WiFi-connected devices. If I repeat the experiment with my laptop, I get "ok" results (34/134/217, no packet loss) but the same laptop similarly has very good results when pinging google.com.

Why might this be? My ultimate goal is to be able to SSH in to this box, but it's unusable as it currently is.

All devices are Linux, if that matters (Arch, specifically).

Comment: did you previously configure IDS or Firewall?

Comment: There's a physical firewall between the LAN and the WAN, but not between the devices on WiFi (at least, insofar as I understand). IDS is disabled on the firewall and devices not on WiFi do not have this problem. I did not configure a software firewall on the devices themselves.